# Old subpanel has dual 60A breaker feeding lighting

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

We've inherited an old house, and the original panel for the house seems to be a subpanel to the new service panel that primarily has electric baseboard heating, and two 20A circuits of receptacles in the kitchen.  In trying to figure out how things are wired up, I found this panel on the back porch behind the kitchen.

The indicated 5-7 double 60A breaker interrupts the lights in several rooms downstairs in the house.

The fading words do not match completely match the switches, but it lists "5 Range", but there is no electric range in the house.  The kitchen has a gas range plugged into one of the new panel's 120V 20A circuits.

Is this breaker reasonable for the lights?  Or did someone hack the lights onto a leg or two of the 60A range circuit?

[image]

I peeked into this kitchen lights switch box, which is controlled by this 60A breaker, and the wires look like relatively new Romex [image]

Comment: The only thing a 60A breaker could reasonably power would be a subpanel or whole house resistive heater (electric HVAC).  Are you sure there's not a subpanel somewhere in the house in a closet or hidden behind something?

Comment: I don't have a picture of the main box, but it has a 100A breaker that feeds this box.   The house has several resistive baseboards on switches in the main box.  The notes on the top two switches in this box hint at two wall-mounted AC units which are plugged into receptacles in the stairs an dining room, but I've not investigated them.  Maybe there is a third box somewhere.

Comment: If indeed there are lights, particularly 120V lights, on the 60A double breaker, then you need to correct that as soon as possible.  That's a dangerous condition on at least two counts.  The 60A breaker will not protect lights which are likely much less than 60A.  The double breaker is for a 240V circuit not a 120V one.

Comment: The fact that it is a double breaker is not necessarily a problem, if it's only using one side

Comment: @MosheKatz Correct, but the problem is 14 or 12 AWG going into a 60 amp breaker.

Comment: What all gets turned off by that 60A double breaker? Does it turn off a bunch of lights and receptacles that are on different circuits?

Comment: It seemed to turn off all the lights on the first floor, maybe some receptacles.  During the afternoon, some folks were working upstairs and didn't notice that the power was off.  I'll have to check next weekend -- the house is 2 hours away.

Comment: I'm sure it's on your to-do list, but a $1 cover plate would sure make that switch look 100% better and would even come with a set of matching cover plate screws. ;)

Comment: @JPhi1618 a hot tub could also conceivably use a 60A circuit. Most are 40A but some are 40A or 60A, especially the latter if it's a large tub with multiple pumps.

Comment: I'd think a new cover plate would likely make it look worse, the current accessory is yellowed but at least it's uniformly yellowed.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### What that thing is.

When the house was built, breakers larger than 60A were *prohibitively* expensive (a bit like 400A breakers today). Now there is a "Rule of Six" - a facility can't have more than 6 handle throws to completely turn off power.  So the answer for >60A services was to have *multiple* main breakers.

You are looking at a **Split Bus** panel. The top 8-12 *breaker spaces* (I suspect 8 on this panel) have their own bus fed straight off the meter.  They are intended for *up to six* "main breakers" that actually power your large 240V appliances (dryer, range, A/C).  *But they also power one "Special" main breaker: called "Lighting Area" breaker*.

Back when these panels were conceived, "Lighting" was the primary use for 120V circuits, hence the name.  Anyway, this 60A "Lighting area" breaker powers **the second bus in the split-bus panel** -- spaces 9-20 I think. 240V circuits are also allowed there.

[image]

### What else was done.

Split-bus panels are kind of dangerous. By design, they are *oversubscribed* - the main breakers add up to more than the service size.  (yours has 60+50+30+30 amps of "main breaker area" breakers; probably on a 100A or 125A service back then).   That was allowed because the **Load Calculation** at build time estimated the draw would be well within limits.  The dangerous bit is upgrades.  You're supposed to re-do the Load Calculation, but nobody ever does.  So, "Rule of Six" main breakers have been banned.

You still see multiple breakers for cost reasons, such as dual 200A breakers on a 400A service, but they're *not* oversubscribed.)

Anyway, at some point, the homeowner upgraded.  They installed a new main panel outside, and made the old split-bus main panel into a subpanel.

There used to be labeling indicating the Main Breaker area, Lighting Area, and Lighting Breaker.  Unfortunately, that faded, fell off or was removed when this panel was subpanel'd.  Removing the label that marked the 60A breaker "Lighting Area" was a Code violation.  All breakers need to be labeled to indicate generally what they power (e.g. "northwest bedroom receptacles" never "Jane's room").

### What you did.

You didn't know what the 60A breaker did, so you turned it off - fair enough.  Yes, it turned off your downstairs lighting.  But it also turned off every breaker in the "Lighting Area" (spaces 9-20).

One of the eleven branch circuit breakers in this area would also turn off the downstairs lighting.

All of that is working as intended, and is a reasonable and legal configuration.  You could even get it approved today in new construction, since the "Rule of Six" panel is being used as a subpanel.

### What to do.

Mostly, not worry about it.

Cutler-Hammer is a subsidiary of Eaton, and this is their flagship "CH" industrial-tier panel. It is the finest panel made for residences.*  If I saw a new one in a Tesla assembly plant being used on 120/208Y, I would not be surprised at all.

The only thing that might make me think about replacing it is if a) there was severe corrosion *inside* the panel, or if b) the split-bus arrangement had frayed my last nerve, or c) I really wanted 6 more spaces.  But swapping the enclosure (outer box) is a total nightmare - you must mark everything, untangle and snake each cable out of its clamp and knockout without damaging wire or markings - it's a PITA.

Instead, I'd make a regular habit of trolling eBay and vintage panel suppliers. *See, panel manufacturers put many sizes of panels into a few "boxes" (enclosures).  That's why you have four breaker knockouts with no breaker spaces behind them, that same lid was used on the 24-space.* If you find a same-vintage 24-space panel that fits this same box, the "entire bus assembly" (everything which is not the outer box) unbolts with 3-4 screws.  Snug all the wires on their breakers, pop the breakers off the bus assembly (without removing wires!), swap bus assemblies, put breakers back on. "Easy peasy".

If it was just the cover that was corroded, I'd just pull it off, prep and re-paint it. That color is called Cutler-Hammer Sandalwood, by the way.

---

* The now-obsolete *Pushmatic* was better, and that's coming from me, a CH "super-fan" lol.

Comment: Ah -- this panel doesn't have the single separated main panel shut-off breaker like I've seen in the few panels I've seen, it has a set of smaller breakers that must all be shut off to kill the power.

Comment: @DaveX yes, it’s not like normal panels, due to the design of the panel, the downstairs lights (and everything else in the lower section) can be shut off by either of two breakers in there.  It's more like a panel *and a subpanel* in the same enclosure.

Comment: Well, CH isn't rated for 277/480Y, but for a 120/208Y circuit, it's quite fine!

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out next weekend.  I'm a bit concerned that the folks working upstairs didn't notice the power was out, but maybe they weren't using any.  I think most of the receptacles and lights (except for the receptacles on the main panel circuits) should be on the 9-20 breakers.  What's the right text to label this 60A breaker for this internal sub-panel?  "Lighting Area" seems too narrow, since it might include the receptacles and the water heater.  I think the 1-3 is 30A for an AC, 2-4, is another 30A AC, and the 6-8 50A is the Dryer.

Comment: @DaveX "Controls below breakers" is best I can think of.  I would myself stick a "Lighting Area" label in the gutter there from 9-20, and mark the breaker itself "Lighting Area [Down Arrow]".  Any experienced electrician will know exactly what they're looking at, at that point.  I would expect any dryer to be 30A and 50A to be more typical of a range.

Answer (score 2):

It could be feeding a sub-panel that feeds the lights. That could be OK. You might not have found that sub-panel yet.

If it's feeding the light circuits directly, that's virtually certainly **not OK.**